# Shuffling a 2d array while keeping columns elements together

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, collections

So I am working on this assignment for a class, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to use the Collections.shuffle() method to shuffle an array comprised of states and their capitals. now when I shuffle the array, it shuffles everything. I need it to shuffle everything, but also keep the relationships between the state and it's capital together as well. (i.e

[Alabama][Montgomery],[Alaska][Juneau],...

shouldn't turn into something like this

[Alabama][Alaska],[Juneau][Montgomery],...

or

[Alaska][Montgomery],[Juneau][Alabama],...

Is there something that I am missing? Here is the working code so far...

```
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Arrays; 
import java.util.Collections; 
import java.util.List; 
import java.util.Random;
/** 
* @author mstashev 
* 
* Rewrite Programming Exercise 8.37 to store the pairs of states and 
* capitals so that the questions are displayed randomly. 
* 
* Exercise 8.37 
* 
* Write a program that repeatedly prompts the user to enter a capital 
* for a state. Upon receiving the user input, the program reports 
* whether the answer is correct. Assume that 50 states and their 
* capitals are stored in a 2D array. The program prompts the user to 
* answer all state's capitals and displays the total correct count. The 
* user's answer is not case-sensitive. 
*/ 
public class RandomStateCapitalQuestionnaire {
/**
 * 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create a 2D array storing all 50 states and capitals
    String[][] twoDStatesAndCapitals = {
            { "Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California",
                    "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida",
                    "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana",
                    "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine",
                    "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota",
                    "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada",
                    "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York",
                    "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma",
                    "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina",
                    "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont",
                    "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin",
                    "Wyoming" },
            { "Montgomery", "Juneau", "Phoenix", "Little Rock", "Sacramento",
                    "Denver", "Hartford", "Dover", "Tallahassee", "Atlanta",
                    "Honolulu", "Boise", "Springfield", "Indianapolis",
                    "Des Moines", "Topeka", "Frankfort", "Baton Rouge",
                    "Augusta", "Annapolis", "Boston", "Lansing", "St. Paul",
                    "Jackson", "Jefferson City", "Helena", "Lincoln",
                    "Carson City", "Concord", "Trenton", "Santa Fe", "Albany",
                    "Raleigh", "Bismark", "Columbus", "Oklahoma City", "Salem",
                    "Harrisburg", "Providence", "Columbia", "Pierre",
                    "Nashville", "Austin", "Salt Lake City", "Montpelier",
                    "Richmond", "Olympia", "Charleston", "Madison", "Cheyenne" }            
        };//End of 2D array
    Random rnd = new Random();

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(twoDStatesAndCapitals));


    List<List<String>> statesAndCapitals = twoDArrayToList(twoDStatesAndCapitals);
    Collections.shuffle(statesAndCapitals, rnd);


    System.out.println(statesAndCapitals);

    /*
     i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_US_STATES; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter the Capital of the State listed: " + statesAndCapitals[i][0]);
        userInput = input.next();
        if (statesAndCapitals[i][1].equals(userInput)) {
            correctStates++;
            System.out.println("Yes that is the capital of " + statesAndCapitals[i][0] + ".");
        }//end of if

        else {
            System.out.println("No that is not the capital of " + statesAndCapitals[i][0] + ".");
            i++;
        }//end of else
    }//end of for loop

    // counts the number of correct guesses.
    System.out.println("Total number of capitals answered correctly: " + correctStates + ".");
    i++;
    return;

    */

}

public static <T> List<List<String>> twoDArrayToList(T[][] twoDArray){
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (T[] array : twoDArray) {
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(array));
    }
    return (List<List<String>>) list;
  }
}
```

Comment: IMO, using a `[2][50]` array is backwards for this application. Using a `[50][2]` array instead allows code to treat a state name and capital name as a unit:  `twoDStatesAndCapitals [4]` would be a 1D array `{"California", "Sacremento"}`, for example. That would allow  `Collections.shuffle (Arrays.asList(twoDStatesAndCapitals));` to work for this application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the right data structure for your problem. You need a list/array of pairs (e.g., `List<Map.Entry<String, String>>`), and call `Collections.shuffle()` on that list.

Comment: Well I haven't been taught about the Map library yet. Is it really easy to use or do I have to write more methods to get it to work properly? And sorry, still a noob at Java

Comment: All the methods you will need are already there. You will mostly just need the `put` method to first populate the map, and then the `get` method if you want to retrieve an entry. The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) will give you all the details for these methods and more.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! That worked great!. (I was looking into it already. haha)