# 2D array for state and capitols, with system asking user input, and then validating answer

Tags: java, string, validation, multidimensional-array, bubble-sort

I am in college and I have this assigment for data structures and algorithms, this is the project:
"Develop a program that asks the user to enter a capital for a U.S. state. Upon receiving the user input, the program reports whether the user input is correct. For this application, the 50 states and their capitals are stored in a two-dimensional array in order by state name. Display the current contents of the array then use a bubble sort to sort the content by capital. Next, prompt the user to enter answers for all the state capitals and then display the total correct count. The user's answer is not case-sensitive."

This is what I have done so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.lang.String;
public class Assignment {
// It begins with the creation of the two dimension array that includes state and capital.
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String[][] StateAndCapital = {
                {"Alabama", "Montgomery"},
                {"Alaska", "Juneau"},
                {"Arizona", "Phoenix"},
                {"Arkansas", "Little Rock"},
                {"California", "Sacramento"},
                {"Colorado", "Denver"},
                {"Connecticut", "Hartford"},
                {"Delaware", "Dover"},
                {"Florida", "Tallahassee"},
                {"Georgia", "Atlanta"},
                {"Hawaii", "Honolulu"},
                {"Idaho", "Boise"},
                {"Illinois", "Springfield"},
                {"Indiana", "Indianapolis"},
                {"Iowa", "Des Moines"},
                {"Kansas", "Topeka"},
                {"Kentucky", "Frankfort"},
                {"Louisiana", "Baton Rouge"},
                {"Maine", "Augusta"},
                {"Maryland", "Annapolis"},
                {"Massachusetts", "Boston"},
                {"Michigan", "Lansing"},
                {"Minnesota", "Saint Paul"},
                {"Mississippi", "Jackson"},
                {"Missouri", "Jefferson City"},
                {"Montana", "Helena"},
                {"Nebraska", "Lincoln"},
                {"Nevada", "Carson City"},
                {"New Hampshire", "Concord"},
                {"New Jersey", "Trenton"},
                {"New Mexico", "Santa Fe"},
                {"New York", "Albany"},
                {"North Carolina", "Raleigh"},
                {"North Dakota", "Bismarck"},
                {"Ohio", "Columbus"},
                {"Oklahoma", "Oklahoma City"},
                {"Oregon", "Salem"},
                {"Pennsylvania", "Harrisburg"},
                {"Rhode Island", "Providence"},
                {"South Carolina", "Columbia"},
                {"South Dakota", "Pierre"},
                {"Tennessee", "Nashville"},
                {"Texas", "Austin"},
                {"Utah", "Salt Lake City"},
                {"Vermont", "Montpelier"},
                {"Virginia", "Richmond"},
                {"Washington", "Olympia"},
                {"West Virginia", "Charleston"},
                {"Wisconsin", "Madison"},
                {"Wyoming", "Cheyenne"}
        };
```

So far I have created the 2d array, I need to have a for loop so the system goes through the array. But I am not sure on how to create a for loop for a two dimension array, I have watched videos for bubble sorting (required for the assignment) and what my lessons mention but they mainly show how to do it on a single dimension array.

```
  for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
     if (array[j] < array [j - 1]) {
      temp = array[j];
      array[j] = array[j - 1];
      array[j - 1] = temp;
```

That is from a lesson, using a single array, but not sure how to do it with a two dimension array.

I also looked into how to convert string to boolean so whenever the user answered, the system would say either "correct answer" or "incorrect answer". If I could get some advice please, I am starting and this may be a dumb question.

I tried changing string value to boolean values so whenever I replied to the system I would get a "correct" or "wrong" answer according to the true/false values assigned to an array of only states, but all answers seemed to say true regardless of my input, which is odd. I am still looking for a way to validate string values.
I have used the scanner to scan the answer given by the user, looked at boolean programs to see if I can see something that I could use but try to make it string-based.

Comment: "all answers seemed to say true regardless of my input" For us to help with that, you should provide example code. But, to avoid risk of having the question closed for lack of focus, I suggest you first fix the bubble sort. When that is working, if something still doesn't work, ask a new question. Reference this question in the new, and add a comment here to reference the new question.

Comment: There are similar questions on Stack Overflow. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31641638/shuffling-a-2d-array-while-keeping-columns-elements-together) also uses names of states and names of their capitals.

Answer (score 0):

You sort the `"2D"` array just like a `"1D"` array.  You have `50` rows and `2` columns. Assuming you know how to sort a `"1D"` array and using `i and j` you would:

- compare `arr[i][1]` against `a[j][1]` to sort by capital
- then, when time swap `arr[i][1] and arr[j][1]` and also swap `arr[i][0] and arr[j][0]`.  (or just like your example sort, but you need to swap both columns on the same row to keep each state and its capital together).

For the quiz, if a state is presented asking for its capital, just prompt for the capital and compare to the correct answer.  Similarly for presenting a capital and asking for state. I recommend you compare everything using lower case to avoid problems in comparing.

Check out the [String](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) class for information on using `compareTo` and `toLowerCase` or `toUpperCase`.

**Updated**

Testing along the way is a good idea, so to ensure you're iterating across them correctly do the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < stateAndCapitals.length; i++){
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stateAndCapitals[i]));
}
```

Comment: So I have re-arranged the array the same way you would do it in a 1d array, States first: {Alabama, Alaska...}, and then capitols: {Montgomery, Juneau....}. And now I see that my array is of length  [1][49], 2 columns and 50 rows. When trying to compare using "i" and "j", I get an error saying "cannot resolve symbol i", how do I identify those two variables? Do I just identify them as int i = 0; and int j = 0;?

Comment: Your array was already properly declared.  1st dimension is # of rows, 2nd dimension  is # of columns.  So each row is a single dimension array of length 2 to hold the state and capital. So you need to iterate over the # of rows which go from `0 to StateAndCapital.length`.  And as noted in the other answer, variables and methods should start with lowercase to conform to Java coding standards.

Comment: So create a for loop for stateAndCapital.length? Yes I am aware of the lowercase for variables and methods now, thank you

Comment: "cannot resolve symbol i" sounds like a typo somewhere. Or you forgot to declare it: `int i;`

Comment: Our answers have been trying to push you in the right direction.  However, we can't keep commenting on errors (especially syntax errors) as you try recommendations from the comments.  If something isn't working, then post a new question and included a  [mre] that will demonstrate the problem.  If it doesn't compile it doesn't qualify as an mre.  For additional help, check out [ask].   And as you haven't taken the [tour] I suggest you do so as it gives more information about the site.

Comment: I prefer the array as in the original question. By _de facto_ standard, that would have 50 rows and 2 columns. Left subscript specifies the row, right subscript the column. So, `stateAndCapital [4][0]` is "California". `stateAndCapital[4][1]` is "Sacremento".

Comment: You can specify a row by using 1 subscript: `stateAndCapital [4]` is a 1D array, `{"California","Sacramento"}`. But, `stateAndCapital [][1]` isn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Java has primitives and reference types. The relational operators `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=` are for primitives. The relational operators `==` and `!=` can be used for either primitives or reference types. For primitives, they compare the values, as expected. For reference types, they don't compare values. They answer the question "Are the operands the *same* reference, that is, the same `Object`?"

To compare values of reference types, methods such as `.equals` or `.compareTo` are used. `String` is a reference type. Comparison of two `Object`s values (not references) typically looks like this:

```
  Foo foo1, foo2;
  ...
  if (foo1.equals (foo2)) ...
```

Sometimes, greater-than or less-than comparisons of values are needed. If a class `implements` [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), objects have a `compareTo` method. The `compareTo` method returns a `int`, which will be a negative number, zero, or a positive to indicate which has the higher value, or that they are equal.

```
  if (foo1.compareTo(foo2) < 0) { 
      System.out.println ("Foo1 is less than Foo2");
   ...
```

`String` does implement `Comparable`.

The [`String` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) offers some methods for comparison:

- `.equals (String  other)`
- `.equalsIgnoreCase (String other)`
- `.compareTo (String other)`
- `.compareToIgnoreCase (String other)`

(2a) For a 2D array, an expression such as `array[j]` references an entire row of `array`, i.e. array[j][0], array[j][1], array[j][2], array[j][3], ...

(2b) To access a single element, you need to specify each subscript.

```
  System.out.println ("The capital of " + stateAndCapital[i][0]
      + " is " + stateAndCapital[i][1] + ".");
```

(3) You want to sort by column 1. So, compare one `stateAndCapital[x][1]` to another `stateAndCapital[y][1]`.

(Remember (2b): Specify both subscripts).

Use `String.compareTo` or `String.compareToIgnoreCase`:

```
  if (stateAndCapital[m][1].compareToIgnoreCase (stateAndCapital[n][1] < 0) { 
      System.out.println (stateAndCapital[m][1] 
        + " comes before " + stateAndCapital[n][1]);
```

When you need to swap, you need to swap both column 1 and column 0 for the indexed row.

You have only two columns to swap. There is a shortcut that becomes more useful the more columns there are: Swap the entire row the same way two Objects are swapped. One way to do that is to make `temp` a 1D array of `String`:

```
   String[] temp;  
   ... 
   temp = stateAndCapital[j];
   stateAndCapital[j] = stateAndCapital[j - 1];
   stateAndCapital[j - 1] = temp;
```

Why does that work? Remember (2a): Arrays are reference types. And a 2D array is really an array of array of the base type.

At least for testing purposes do these:

- Fix the bubble sort using the 3 issues above.
- Print the the state names and capitals from the original array.
- Do the bubble sort.
- Print the state names and capitals again.

Note: I used `stateAndCapital` instead of `StateAndCapital` to conform to Java naming convention.

Comment: Inadvertently edited you answer.  Changed it back.  The order keeps switching.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to create a class, so each Object has a state name and the name of the capital city.

```
 public class StateAndCapital implements Comparable {
     private String stateName;
     private String capitalName;

     public StateAndCapital (String state, String capital) {
         stateName = state;
         capitalName = capital;
     }
     public String getStateName () { return stateName; }
     public String getCapitalName () { return capitalName; }
     public int compareTo (StateAndCapital other) { 
         int i = this.capital.compareTo (other.capital);
         if (i == 0) { 
              i = this.stateName.compareTo (other.stateName );
         }
         return i;
     }
 }
```

Then, you would have a 1D array.

```
  public static void main (String[] args) {
     StateAndCapital [] stateCapital = { 
            new StateAndCapital ("Alabama", "Montgomery"),
            new StateAndCapital ("Alaska", "Juneau"),
            new StateAndCapital ("Arizona", "Phoenix"),
            new StateAndCapital ("Arkansas", "Little Rock"),
            ...
            };
            ... 
  }
```

Then, in your bubble sort code, use the actual name of your array, and do a comparison like this:

```
      if (stateCapital[j].compareTo(stateCapital [j - 1])) ...
```

Comment: The O/P is required to use a 2D array. While creating a new class might be better design, it would fail to meet the requirements placed by the proessor.