# So I'm trying to see if there is a way to count correct inputs and allow multiple inputs with boolean match. Am I able to do this?

Tags: java, arrays, string, boolean, java.util.scanner

So I've tried adding count ++ in multiple places in my code along with researching some way to allow multiple inputs to no avail.  Am I missing something on placement or would I need to rewrite the code entirely for what I am wanting to accomplish? Is this not a boolean match situation?  Very lost and sorry if this is a noob question.  Appreciate the input.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Insert any State Capital");
String currentInput = scanner.nextLine();

boolean match = false;
            
            String [] capitals = stateCapitals[1];
            for (String capital:capitals) {
                if (capital.equalsIgnoreCase(currentInput)) {
                    match = true;
                    break;
                    }
                
                }


if (match) {
                System.out.println ("Correct");
                
            }
            else
                System.out.println ("incorrect");
            }
            }
```

Problem and what I've tried is above.  Also, apologies on formatting if it's messed up.  First time using stack overflow.

Comment: This appears to be an attempt to ask the user to input the name of a state capital, and then test the input to see if it is, in fact, the name of a state capital. The program will output either `Correct` or `incorrect`. I don't see any attempt to count anything. There are two problems with the code: `String [] capitals = stateCapitals[1];`  1) This is an array of 1 element. You probably want an array of 50 elements.  2) The `capitals` array doesn't really contain names of capitals.

Comment: For an example of how to initialize a `String` array with literals, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31641638/shuffling-a-2d-array-while-keeping-columns-elements-together .

Comment: For another example, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74355188/2d-array-for-state-and-capitols-with-system-asking-user-input-and-then-validat . Note that this is a 2D array, as in the previous example, while you want a 1D array.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer I should add that I created a 2d array earlier in the code(not shown because I thought it would be a little too long for my question, and used the scanner class to get user input.  That's where this snippet is coming from.  I'm just wondering if there's a way where I can maybe turn this into something that allows multiple inputs with a correct/false response without ending the program after the first correct and the ablility to also count the correct answers. Is this possible?  I had tried adding count++ under the match = true line but was getting an error.

Comment: Looks like you took the advice to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Perhaps you overdid it, making it subminimal.  But, in any case, I'm not sure what you are asking. Perhaps including some examples would help?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below code and let me know if this solves your issue.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> inputList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> capitalList = new ArrayList<>(List.of("Delhi","Kabul","Dhaka"));
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            
            String currentInput = scanner.nextLine();
            inputList.add(currentInput);
            
        }
        
        int correct_response_count = 0;
        int wrong_response_count = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < inputList.size(); i++)
        {
           if (capitalList.contains(inputList.get(i)))
           {
               correct_response_count++;
           }
           else
           {
               wrong_response_count++;
           }
   
        }
        
        System.out.println("The correct count of answers is: " + correct_response_count);
        System.out.println("The wrong count of answers is: " + wrong_response_count);
        
        
    }
}
```

Input

```
India
Delhi
Australia
Kabul
Bangladesh
```

Output

```
The correct count of answers is: 2
The wrong count of answers is: 3
```